# What is the impact or relevance of previously accepted patents for employment oppotunities in IT?

Tags: interviewing, patent

I have had a couple of employers ask me if I have an existing patent. Why is this relevant please? How does having or not having one impact future employment opportunities? Please elaborate on the whether there is a difference between private sector vs. government

Is there any difference in how private organizations look at inventors vs. Government? For instance, I recently found out there are restrictions on individuals who work for the Patent office in terms of submitting patents or even helping friends with the process. My question is how would an existing patent impact any chance submitting another one in the future if you agree to a typical patent and invention clause?

Comment: "Can I also add a gripe?" - No, you cannot. This is a site for fact-based question and answer, not for starting opinion-based discussions, so I removed the portions that do not directly affect the question you asked. If you want to ask about how to negotiate a patent agreement at a new job, that's different enough that I would post that as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Like any other accomplishment, a patent is going to be irrelevant for some jobs, impressive but not terribly relevant for some jobs (however it could help you stand out from the crowd), negative for some jobs,  and a huge plus, if not a requirement, for a few jobs.

The vast majority of software positions do not require having a patent although it is something that might make a difference when looking at two relatively equal people. I doubt it would significantly harm your job prospects overall however although some individual positions might turn you down. It is unlikely that most software positions would turn you down **only** for that reason unless the particular position involves very high level computer science research.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that come to mind for me.

**1. Measure your ability and inventiveness**

When looking at new hires, I would value someone who has generated patents in the past. This tells me that they are creative, intelligent, and very good at solving problems. Additionally, if you have created patents before, there's a good chance that you will make them again. Depending on your contract, this could mean new patents and revenue for my company.

**2. Conflicts of interest**

If you have any active patents that you are currently getting payouts, this could be seen as a conflict of interest, particularly if the patent is held by a competitor. This is not an outright negative for you, but like any COI, you would need to declare it and explain why it shouldn't be an issue going forward.

Answer (score 0):

> I have had a couple of employers ask me if I have an existing patent.
>   Why is this relevant please?

It's a precautionary measure. It helps avoid potential disputes about patents filed while you are employed with the company.

You should disclose any patents or pending patents so that the company won't feel that you developed the technology while with the company (in which case they may become the patent holder).

Comment: So, if I submit get a patent associated with some technology, then I can work for these companies after disclosing that? Would that provide protection for any patents I submit for the same technology if I happen to work with that technology at the new place? ( I hope I did not confuse you)